# My footer disappears after the first page (but not the header!) in R-Markdown

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, pdflatex

I have a footer and header set by using the fancyhdr package in a R-Markdown generated PDF. However, at some point I notcied my footer disappears after the first page, while my header appears in each page as intended. I have no idea why can it be, I tried lots of stuff but nothing seemed to work so far.

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot{}
- \fancyhead{}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

... (some chunks of code go here)

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{/Users/username/Documents/SP_logo_login.png}}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \\ \today , \currenttime}
\fancyfoot[L]{Identification Report \\ User generating the report: {`r paste(user_code)`}}

\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

# IDENTIFICATION REPORT

(some more LaTex and code chunks follow, including bar plots and KableExtra tables)

...
```

It does not matter wether I put the fancyfoot after some code or right under header-includes. The result is the same. The footer is correctly generated on the first page, but that's all, while the header appears at the beginning of every page.

Any idea on what could be going on?

Comment: Can you intercept the resulting .tex file?

Comment: Can you narrow down the Rmd to a [mcve]? Intercepting the `.tex` file as asked by @samcarter is possible via `output.pdf_document.keep_tex: yes`.

Comment: @samcarter as I tried to perform a minimal reproducible example I discovered something. It is the header which generates the conflict. If instead of using \includegraphics I just replace all that by a character ("Hello"), then both header and footer appear to all the pages. So it must be something related to uploading the picture in the header.

Comment: @MarcBF My suspicion would be an issue with the headheight, but I would need to have a small tex document to test. Do you get any warnings about the headheight in the .log file?

Comment: @samcarter I get the following:
`Warning message:
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 144.
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's E' option without twoside option is use
less on input line 145.`

Comment: @MarcBF Can you show the tex file?

Comment: The most probable cause of the problem is an unsuitable value for the head or foothight, but without seeing the tex code it is hard to guess which value solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your headline is much higher than the default `\headheight` and therefore pushes the content and the footline off the page. There is an explicit warning in the `.log` which tells you how height the headline needs to be. The exact value will depend on the aspect ration of your image, for the example image I used, it is about 75pt

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true

header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot{}
- \fancyhead{}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}    
- \geometry{head=75pt, includehead=true, includefoot=true}

---

... (some chunks of code go here)

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \\ \today}
\fancyfoot[L]{Identification Report \\ User generating the report: }

\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

# IDENTIFICATION REPORT

(some more LaTex and code chunks follow, including bar plots and KableExtra tables)

...
```